# How to configure Netgear WGR614v9 as a Wireless Repeater (without a physical cable)

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, repeater

I have a Binatone wifi router acting as my base station:

```
Model: Binatone WR1500N2
LAN Port
MAC Address 0C:D2:B6:37:02:F6
IP Address  192.168.0.1
DHCP    ON
IP Subnet Mask  255.255.255.0
```

I have a Netgear router that I want to use as a wireless repeater.

```
Model: Netgear WGR614v9
LAN Port
MAC Address 00:24:B2:A9:C2:AE
IP Address  192.168.0.2
DHCP    ON
IP Subnet Mask  255.255.255.0
```

Here are the wireless repeater settings at both the routers:
[image: Wireless Repeater config screengrabs]

I do not want to run a physical cable between the two routers, but the configuration I have been able to do requires a cable to be run.

I googled and found that I need 'Wireless repeater & bridging' option, but I cannot find it in the router page.

DD-WRT does not support this router. Is there a work-around?

Comment: Have you looked into router compatibility with OpenWrt or TomatoWrt?

Answer (score 5):

So this is my mistake.

1. The 2 routers, the base station (Binatone) and the repeater unit
   (Netgear WGR614v9) have to be assigned the **SAME SSID**.
2. The 2 routers have to use the **SAME Authentication Mode** (WEP in my
   case, since the netgear only supports WEP in repeater mode).
3. Both APs must use the same channel (this part I had gotten right)

In my case, I had configured the base station SSID and repeater SSID differently. Also I had used WPA2 on the base station and WEP on my repeater.

You can find a full documentation for the Netgear WGR614v9 [here](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WGR614V9/WGR614v9_UM_14May08.pdf). Hope this helps someone else.